# How to Set Screen Resolution At run time

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-resolution

i have a problem guys i made a wpf applications its running well but when i change the  resolution of my screen my all form control are not on their positions is any body tell me why this problem come and what are the solution to reform this..

thanks in advance
Radhe Govind

Comment: Can you be a bit specific in stating your problem? What is repositioned where? Illustrate with some code.

Comment: my half form is to be lost-and another half part showing on full screen.

Comment: i m not using ANY CODE FOR RESOLUTION

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of absolute sizes that you might have used.

Comment: absolute sizes OF MY WINDOW FORM